# Employ % as wildcard

Tags: mysql, sql

I am learning sql following sql in 10 minutes and confused about the wildcard symbol of %

```
#+begin_src sql :engine mysql :dbuser org :database grocer
 select prod_id, prod_name from Products where prod_name like  "fish%";
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
| prod_id | prod_name         |
|---------+-------------------|
| BNBG01  | Fish bean bag toy |
```

Universally, * is the wildcard and thus regex as well does not go very far from it which use dot as wildcards.

However, SQL use % as wildcards.

What' the reason sql have to drop *, except that since I invented the lanuage, just call me Dad.

Comment: What is your question?  The wildcard for `like` in SQL is `'%'`.  Is there something unclear about that?

Comment: In additiona an asterisk is already used in the select statement, as in `SELECT * FROM`

Comment: My question is what's the convention it take? where does the % originate as wildcards?  * is definitely better.

Comment: The `%` was defined back in 1986 when the first SQL standard was created.

Comment: You can also ask, why the french call an Eggplant an Aubergine. It's a different language therefore not a useful question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asterisk `*` is already wildcard in SQL syntax, like in `SELECT * FROM tbl`, meaning "all columns".

The percentage `%` was chosen to distinguish between `*` which is a syntax wildcard and text/content wildcard, which is a different thing.

Comment: Can you provide a reference for _The percentage % was chosen to distinguish between * which is a ..._?

Comment: I did not get your idea, reasoning is prohibited by you?  @SalmanA

Comment: @SalmanA well, it's probably in the standard, but unfortunately "it seems that SQL-86 is lost in the age of the internet".  see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/168595/where-can-i-find-the-first-standardization-of-sql-sql-86

Comment: Well if it was about distinguishing one thing from another then the authors clearly forgot to distinguish between `*` for `<asterisk>` and `*` for multiplication.

Comment: I found regexp_like thus could forget %.

Comment: @Alice be aware that regexp_like will never use any clever index access strategy, while `LIKE 'test%'` does an index range scan, which might make a huge difference in performance depending on the amount of data in the table.